# Calculating aged tickets open at a given point in time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Background:**
We have a ticketing system and each ticket has fields such as open date, close date, category, type, etc. Each ticket is represented by one row in my data with a key to identify the ticket.

An individual record might look like:

```
Number, Type, Category, Opened, Closed
TICKET100, Database, Software, 2/1/2020 11:30 AM, 4/22/2020 4:40 PM
```

**Goal:**
My goal is to create a function that takes an input dataframe (pandas), some type of input age parameter, and a list of attributes/dimensions. The function would then return a dataframe of how many tickets were open past a certain age based on that age parameter, by each of the attributes/dimensions, by date.

**Example of input:**

```
ticket_age(input_dataframe, age=5, dimensions=['Type','Category'])
```

**Example snippet of desired output:**

```
Date, Type, Category, Count
3/1/2020, Database, Software, 1
3/2/2020, Database, Software, 1
...
4/22/2020, Database, Software, 0
```

An important note about the output... if the intersection of the date and the dimensions doesn't have any tickets that satisfy the condition, it should create a row with a count of 0.

**Where I'm stuck:**
I have no idea how to accept the dimensions of a list of unknown size and iterate through all of them.

**What have I tried?** I've been *successful* in generating the ticket counts that meet the age criteria when I hard code the loops through dimensions.

**How I calculate type_list, first_date, and total_days:**

```
    #Create function to find the minimum date
def date_minimum(input_dataframe, date_to_check):
    return input_dataframe[date_to_check].min().date()

#Create function to find the maximum date
def date_maximum(input_dataframe,date_to_check):
    return input_dataframe[date_to_check].max().date()

    #setup min and max dates
    min_date=date_minimum(df_aged_input,'Opened')
    max_date=date_maximum(df_aged_input,'Closed')
    #Get the first relevant date for the dataframe loop
    first_date=min_date+datetime.timedelta(days=aged_window)

    # Generate a list of unique assignment groups
    type_list=df_aged_input['Type'].unique().tolist()
```

**My loop**

```
aged_output_list=[]
for type_iterate in range(len(type_list)):
    #filter by the type
    aged_type=type_list[type_iterate]
    df_aged_input=df_tkt_relevant[df_tkt_relevant['Type']==aged_type].copy()
    for date_iterate in range(totalDays.days):
        #generate the aged date iterator
        aged_date=first_date+datetime.timedelta(days=date_iterate)
        #Count the number of records in the data frame that match the input conditions
        aged_frame=df_aged_input[(~(df_aged_input['Closed'].dt.date<aged_date))&(df_aged_input['Opened'].dt.date<(aged_date-datetime.timedelta(days=aged_window+1)))].copy()
        aged_frame['aged_Date']=aged_date-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        aged_count=aged_frame.shape[0]
        #Write the date from iterative date and the aged count to a new data source
        aged_output_list.append([aged_date,aged_type or 'Error: Missing Type',aged_count])
```

**What do I do next? Is there another library that does all of this for me?**

Comment: This can be done quick using just pandas method, can you explain a bit more about the `age` parameter, what is the relationship between age and date? and also is `count` the number of tickets in the dataframe for that specific date?

Comment: Put another way, how many tickets were open for 5 (age=5) days or more as of 2020-03-01 (the date_iterate).

Comment: There is a row in the description that says `4/22/2020, Database, Software, 0` it means in that day there were no tickets for the `type` and the `category`, do you need this same output for all dates that fit `age` parameter?

Comment: It means that there's no tickets on 4/22/2020, of Type==Database, and Category==Software, that had been open for 5 days or more as of 4/22/2020.

Comment: @ChrisG where are the dates in the output coming from?

Comment: @ChrisG there are undefined variables...I do not know what `first_date`, `totalDays` or `type_list` are.

Comment: @Yo_Chris: code updates added. First date and totalDays attempt to reduce unnecessary iterations.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. Starting to get a better understanding. One thing I am still unclear on is `TotalDays` and the expected output. The dates in the expected output seem arbitrary `[3/1/2020, 3/2/2020, 4/22/2020]` can you provide a little more information about the expected output

Comment: @Yo_Chris: thank you for the good questions. The dates I provided were fairly arbitrary now that I look back at it. I've added an ellipsis to hopefully suggest all dates between. Technically, it should be all days between (inclusive) the 'first date' and the 'max date'

Comment: @ChrisG perfect, I understand now. One more question, can you have multiple rows with the same `Number`: `['ticket100', 'ticket101', 'ticket100']`

Comment: @Yo_Chris: I'm not sure which question you're asking, so I'm going to answer many.  The input dataframe/dataset will only have one row per ticket number...ie ticket100.  However, one ticket number can be counter multiple times in the output.  If a ticket took 60 days to close, it'll appear as a 5 day old ticket 55 times? Can multiple tickets be counted in a single output row? Yes, because Ticket100 and Ticket101 can both be 5 days old on the same date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

# sample data
s = """Number,Type,Category,Opened,Closed
TICKET100,Database,Software,2/1/2020 11:30 AM,2/22/2020 4:40 PM
TICKET101,Database,Software,2/10/2020 11:30 AM,2/23/2020 4:40 PM
TICKET102,Database,Software,2/11/2020 11:30 AM,2/22/2020 4:40 PM
TICKET103,something,else,2/10/2020 11:30 AM,2/23/2020 4:40 PM
TICKET104,something,else,2/12/2020 11:30 AM,2/22/2020 4:40 PM"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# convert to datetime
df['Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opened'])
df['Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Closed'])

# create a function
def myFunc(df, age, dimensions):
    # zip the date offset for open and close together
    z = zip(df['Opened'].dt.date + DateOffset(age), df['Closed'].dt.date - DateOffset(age))
    # create a daterange for each record in the dataframe
    df['date_range'] = [pd.date_range(o, c, freq='D') for o,c in z]
    # groupby your dimensions columns
    g = df.groupby(dimensions)
    # list comprehension for each group and create the date range
    idxs = [pd.date_range(df['Opened'].min(), df['Closed'].max(), freq='D',
                          normalize=True) for _,df in g]
    # sum all the true values where the datetime index create above
    # is in the date_range column
    l = [[sum(df[1]['date_range'].apply(lambda x: idx.isin(x))),
          idx, [df[0]]*len(idx)] for idx,df  in zip(idxs, g)]
    # transpose and hstack the list
    arr = np.transpose(np.hstack(l))
    # return pandas dataframe
    return pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['count', 'date', 'dimensions'])

out = myFunc(df, 5, ['Type', 'Category'])

    count       date             dimensions
0       0 2020-02-01  (Database, Software)
1       0 2020-02-02  (Database, Software)
2       0 2020-02-03  (Database, Software)
3       0 2020-02-04  (Database, Software)
4       0 2020-02-05  (Database, Software)
5       1 2020-02-06  (Database, Software)
6       1 2020-02-07  (Database, Software)
7       1 2020-02-08  (Database, Software)
8       1 2020-02-09  (Database, Software)
9       1 2020-02-10  (Database, Software)
10      1 2020-02-11  (Database, Software)
11      1 2020-02-12  (Database, Software)
12      1 2020-02-13  (Database, Software)
13      1 2020-02-14  (Database, Software)
14      2 2020-02-15  (Database, Software)
15      3 2020-02-16  (Database, Software)
16      3 2020-02-17  (Database, Software)
17      1 2020-02-18  (Database, Software)
18      0 2020-02-19  (Database, Software)
19      0 2020-02-20  (Database, Software)
20      0 2020-02-21  (Database, Software)
21      0 2020-02-22  (Database, Software)
22      0 2020-02-23  (Database, Software)
23      0 2020-02-10     (something, else)
24      0 2020-02-11     (something, else)
25      0 2020-02-12     (something, else)
26      0 2020-02-13     (something, else)
27      0 2020-02-14     (something, else)
28      1 2020-02-15     (something, else)
29      1 2020-02-16     (something, else)
30      2 2020-02-17     (something, else)
31      1 2020-02-18     (something, else)
32      0 2020-02-19     (something, else)
33      0 2020-02-20     (something, else)
34      0 2020-02-21     (something, else)
35      0 2020-02-22     (something, else)
36      0 2020-02-23     (something, else)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yo_Chris. I'll validate and respond over the next 24 hours.

Comment: @ChrisG, no problem, let me know if you run into any issues. Also, looking back through your question I may have made up the part about `df['Closed'] - DateOffset(age)` in `z = zip(...)` You may need to remove the `DateOffset` for `df['Closed']` because right now the ticket has to be open for a minimum of what `age` is set to and the ticket has to have a close date minus the age. That is why index 18-22 and index 32-36 have a count of 0

Comment: Thank you yo_chris, I'm still going through refactoring and can't confirm pro/con...but you deserve the bounty since you attempted to help.